# Why is Object.class not the same as new Object().getClass()?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have following Java classes:

```
class Model { // some model class }

class FooModel extends Model {}

class ModelWorker {
  public static <T extends Model> void do(Class<T> clazz) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Why is the `ModelWorker.do()` method capable for `FooModel.class` but not for
`new FooModel().getClass()` ?

Comment: `do` is not a legal identifier.

Comment: what do you mean by "not capable"?

Comment: Question needs to be clarified. (Assume that do() is renamed.) As described here `do(FooModel.class)` and `do(new FooModel().getClass())` both work fine. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your dummy code should work. However, since it's clearly just an example, I suspect your true code is a bit different.

See the specification for [`Object.getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29).

> **The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called.**

Notice it returns `Class<?>`? This means that doing something like

```
Object o = new FooModel();
ModelWorker._do(o.getClass());
```

... would correctly fail to compile, since `o.getClass()` is merely `Class<?>`. Are you doing something like this?

Comment: Well, for me it works I I remove the type hints outside of the signature of do() ...

Comment: @Hannes does that mean you're using raw types? or are you accepting `Class<T>` with `T` unbound?

Comment: No, more like
public static void do(Class<T extends Model> clazz) { /* ... */ }
instead of
public static <T extends Model> void do(Class<T> clazz) { /* ... */ }

Comment: If you just have `static void do(Class<T extends Model> clazz)` then where does the T come from?